# Include folder with same name that other in exclude in rsync

Tags: rsync

So I have this code:

```
rsync \
   --archive \
   --verbose \
   --compress \
   --delete \
   --no-motd \
   --exclude=.git* \
   --exclude=.idea \
   --exclude=.tags \
   --exclude=vendor \
   --exclude=tags \
   --exclude=node_modules \
   --rsync-path="sudo rsync" \
   "${src}"/ \
   "${profile}":"${dst}"
```

And it works beautiful! But I have a problem... with this tree structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── vendor/
├── vendor/
```

It does not work. I want exclude only `./vendor` but include `./app/vendor`. I've tried with `--include` but the result is the same: `app/vendor` is excluded always.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's two ways to do this:

1. With `--include`:

   ```
   rsync \
      .... \
      --include=app/vendor \
      --exclude=vendor \
      ....
   ```

   I.e. put the `--include` *before* the `--exclude`
2. With a more specific `--exclude`:

   ```
   rsync \
       .... \
       --exclude=/vendor \
       ....
   ```

   I.e. exclude only the `vendor` in the source directory root (not to be confused with the filesystem root).

The basic rule for include/exclude rules is that rsync will use the *first* rule that matches any given file. You put your specific rules at the top, and the general rules at the bottom. If you get them backward you'll find that your specific override does not work.